# Как отключить USB при выключенном ПК?

Tags: usb, мышь, пк

Как отключить USB при выключенном ПК? У меня мышка светиться ночью (когда ПК выключен).

Comment: В биосе найдите настройку режима Stendby и выключите его. Если там нет такой настройки, то прочитайте инструкцию к материнской плате вашего компьютера для отключения этого режима джамперами на материнке.

Comment: @Visman а чего не в ответы ?)

Comment: Так может не поможет :)

Comment: Ну и пусть светится - не шумит же) Можно её коробкой накрыть :D